# Showing that every digit occurs infinitely often as a leading digit of a power of $2$ *using topological dynamics*

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, dynamical-systems, topological-groups

I cite [this](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Eeisner/book-EFHN.pdf) book, mostly from $37$ onwards until the exercises - this is exercise $12$, page $40$. It is left as an exercise to show that the leading digits of the powers of two contain all digits infinitely often, and I fully intend to finish this exercise - I just am at a loss as to how to get started. The issue is that the problem must be phrased in terms of topological dynamics.

The contents of the book so far, chapters 1-3, covers topological dynamical systems - compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ endowed with a continuous map $\phi:X\to X$, and whether or not they contain recurrent points. By "recurrent", it is meant that $x$ is recurrent when the set $\phi(x),\phi^2(x),\cdots,\phi^n(x),\cdots$ is dense in $X$, and uniformly recurrent whenever the set $\{m\in\Bbb N_1:\phi^m(x)\in U\}$ is syndetic (of bounded gaps) for all open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$.

The authors, in the example questions, consider some simple systems such as $[0,1)$ with addition modulo $1$, or rotational groups, and a common theme is to *extend* a system:

> The extension of $(X;\phi)$ by a compact space $Y$, *along* a continuous function $\lambda:X\times Y\to Y$, is the product topological space $X\times Y$ endowed with the dynamic $\psi(x,y)=(\phi(x),\lambda(x,y))$

> The *group* extension of $(X;\phi)$ by a compact group $(G,\circ)$, along a continuous function $\lambda:X\to G$, is the product topological space $X\times G$ endowed with the dynamic $\psi(x,g)=(\phi(x),\lambda(x)\circ g)$.

Arguments in previous examples, such as Diophantine approximation, have broadly followed the lines of:

Consider the dynamical system $K$, show that a certain point $x$ is recurrent. Then extend (possibly multiple times) by another space or group along a convenient function $\lambda$ such that $\psi^n$ inductively follows a nice pattern, (such as $2^n$) and then use theorem from book such as: points recurrent in a system remain recurrent in the extension of that system, and every point of a rotational compact group is uniformly recurrent, to obtain that $x$ is recurrent in the extended system, and therefore: "there exists $n$ such that $\psi^n$ - our nice inductive expression, such as $2^n$, is very close to the desired point for any $\epsilon$", etc.

In this case, I seek to show that the point $m,\,m\in\{1,2,\cdots,9\}$, is uniformly recurrent in some space with a dynamic that involves the leading digits of the powers of two.

**How I can actually make the link to a dynamical system**, possibly after extension, is beyond me. I suppose $G=\{2^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$, $a\circ b=ab$ forms a group, but how do I extract the leading digit? Moreover, how I make this *topological*? - The space must be compact and Hausdorff...

If anyone can point me to a suitable system, or even better, make a meaningful hint so that I can understand how to come up with these things myself, I'd appreciate it. I admit I am punching above my weight with this text, not very fluent in topology, group theory as I am, but I want to keep going as far as possible as it's quite interesting.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718333/are-there-infinitely-many-n-such-that-2n-and-3n-both-have-first-digit-7?rq=1

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658306/rate-of-appearance-of-digits-7-and-8-in-a-given-sequence/658445, for example.

Comment: @HansLundmark Those arguments I have seen - they’re just not applications of dynamic theory.

Comment: @r.e.s. What does $\langle,\rangle$ mean in the context of Brian’s answer? Thank you for that post

Comment: @FShrike Just a tuple, as best I can tell.

Comment: @FShrike: If $x \mapsto x + \ln 2 \pmod{1}$ is not a dynamical system, I don't know what is...

Comment: @HansLundmark I was replying to the first post, apologies